# PostSharp OnExceptionAspect not working as expected

Tags: postsharp

Created a simple class to test out the OnExceptionAspect in PostSharp.

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ExceptionSwallower : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        eventArgs.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return; 
        base.OnException(eventArgs);  
    }
}
```

Added the attribute to a method

```
    [ExceptionSwallower]
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

and invoked it.

However, the exception is not actually swallowed, which seems odd.

I haven't been able to find any similar problems, so I expect there is some minor thing I haven't gotten right. Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

You can check a build output:
It can give some hint was post-processing involved or not , e.g.
POSTSHARP : postsharp warning PS0131: The module 'YourAssembly.dll' does not contain any aspect or other transformation. For improved build-time performance, consider disabling PostSharp for this module by setting the compilation symbol (aka constant) 'SkipPostSharp' in your project, or set the MSBuild property 'SkipPostSharp=True'.
  : message : PostSharp complete -- 0 errors, 1 warnings, served in 1637 ms

Comment: +1 for making me realize the reason my aspect wasn't working was because I had the SkipPostSharp constant set to true since until now I didn't use aspects in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to look at the resulting assembly using Reflector. PostSharp generates plain .NET assemblies, there is no magic.

Comment: Pfft... come on Gael, we all know PostSharp references System.Magic.